# How do you align text with SVG elements?

Tags: css, svg

I have a bunch of SVG icons and text to go with them. However, the text doesn't align with the icons. See this code:

```html
<span class="cardSpan">
    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path fill="#000000" d="M12 4C14.2091 4 16 5.79086 16 8C16 10.2091 14.2091 12 12 12C9.79086 12 8 10.2091 8 8C8 5.79086 9.79086 4 12 4ZM12 14C16.4183 14 20 15.7909 20 18L20 20L4 20L4 18C4 15.7909 7.58172 14 12 14Z"></path>
    </svg>
       John Johnson
</span>
<p>

<span class="cardSpan">
    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path fill="#000000" d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
    </svg>
       Streetlane 123
</span>
</p>

<p>
<span class="cardSpan">
    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path fill="#000000" d="M14,10V4.5L19.5,10M5,3C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V9L15,3H5Z" />
    </svg>
       These are some cool notes.
</span>
</p>
```

My question: how do I align the text to the center of every SVG icon next to it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

See the demo below:

```css
.icon,
.text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="cardSpan">
  <span class="icon">
    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M12 4C14.2091 4 16 5.79086 16 8C16 10.2091 14.2091 12 12 12C9.79086 12 8 10.2091 8 8C8 5.79086 9.79086 4 12 4ZM12 14C16.4183 14 20 15.7909 20 18L20 20L4 20L4 18C4 15.7909 7.58172 14 12 14Z"></path></svg>
  </span>
  <span class="text">John Johnson</span>
</span>

<p>
  <span class="cardSpan">
    <span class="icon">
      <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path fill="#000000" d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="text">Streetlane 123</span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="cardSpan">
    <span class="icon">
      <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path fill="#000000" d="M14,10V4.5L19.5,10M5,3C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V9L15,3H5Z" />
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="text">These are some cool notes.</span>
  </span>
</p>
```